# Ruby. Get an average value of array IF dates are equal

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays

```
[
 [3, "2014-06-28"], 
 [3, "2014-06-29"], 
 [3, "2014-06-30"], 
 [27, "2014-07-02"], 
 [7, "2014-07-02"]
]
```

If the dates are equal I want to get an average of their values so the above array would become

```
[
 [3, "2014-06-28"], 
 [3, "2014-06-29"], 
 [3, "2014-06-30"], 
 [17, "2014-07-02"], 
]
```

The array is already sorted by date.

How would I go about this? Do I use a recursive function?

Comment: ok you want the average of second column where dates are same? right ?

Comment: And what about first column? Should it be the average too?

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity

Comment: Is your array sorted by date by default? :)

Comment: yes it is sorted by date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [
        [3, "2014-06-28"], 
        [3, "2014-06-29"], 
        [3, "2014-06-30"], 
        [27, "2014-07-02"], 
        [7, "2014-07-02"]
      ]

arr.group_by(&:last).map do |k, vs|
  av = vs.map(&:first).inject(:+) / vs.size.to_f
  [av, k]
end

#=> [
#=>   [3.0, "2014-06-28"], 
#=>   [3.0, "2014-06-29"], 
#=>   [3.0, "2014-06-30"], 
#=>   [17.0, "2014-07-02"]
#=> ]
```

If you're looking for more optimized but less idiomatic solution (and your data set is ordered by date) you could follow this:

```
arr = [
        [3, "2014-06-28"], 
        [3, "2014-06-29"], 
        [3, "2014-06-30"], 
        [27, "2014-07-02"], 
        [7, "2014-07-02"]
      ]

res = []
tmp = [0]
cnt = 0
arr.each do |num, date|
  if tmp[1] && tmp[1] != date
    tmp[0] /= cnt.to_f
    res << tmp
    tmp = [0]
    cnt = 0
  end
  tmp[0] += num
  tmp[1] = date
  cnt += 1
end
tmp[0] /= cnt.to_f
res << tmp
res

#=> [
#=>   [3.0, "2014-06-28"], 
#=>   [3.0, "2014-06-29"], 
#=>   [3.0, "2014-06-30"], 
#=>   [17.0, "2014-07-02"]
#=> ]
```

Comment: If I had an extra value in each array say for example `[1400496920000, 2, "2014-05-19"]`. How would I edit your second example to average the second value in the array?

Comment: What should be the result? Array of arrays of two items or three items?